# How can I make a text widget in tkinter that fills its grid position?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to using `grid_rowconfigure()` and `grid_columnconfigure()` but from my understanding, the code below should make a centered textbox that has space either side:

```
self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

Box = tk.Text(self, height=2, pady=4)
Box.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

However, the `Text` widget is the default width. How can I make it so it fills the column width (based on weight)?

I thought about placing a frame in the grid then packing the textbox within the frame to fill it but it looks the same as this.

UPDATE:

I used `sticky="nsew"` and that seems to work for the vertical height but not the horizontal height.

Fix: added a value for width in `Box`

Working Code:

```
self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

Box = tk.Text(self, height=2, width=2, pady=4)
Box.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: Use `sticky="ew"` in `grid(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `sticky` attribute to cause a widget to fill the space given to it.

```
Box.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=“nsew”)
```